# Making buttons mixed case on Android from Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, button, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamrin. I am attempting to build a Xamarin Forms app (as little native as possible) for running on both Android and IOS.

I am running in the Android Emulator and by buttons all have uppercase text even though I'm specifying text in mixed case.

I have found a number of pages that say to add the following to styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```

and another that referenced:

```
<item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
```

It looks like, though, that there's been some changes according to the docs in styles.xml, so I added it and it now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <!-- As of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 the theme has moved into the Forms binary -->
    <!-- If you want to override anything you can do that here. -->
    <!-- Underneath are a couple of entries to get you started. -->

    <!-- Set theme colors from https://aka.ms/material-colors -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>-->
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>-->
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <!--<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>-->
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

But when I run the emulator, it shows all button text in all uppercase.

I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Custom Renderer for button and set the **SetAllCaps** to **false** and try.

**Here is the Code:**

```
public class CustomButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Cleanup
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
           var button = (Button)this.Control; 
           button.SetAllCaps(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw that as an option, but was hoping I wouldn't have to resort to that.

Comment: Can you override the default renderer or do you have to create a custom control?

Comment: Yes, This custom renderer itself overrides the Default behavior.

Comment: Getting this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137924/override-conversion-errors-when-creating-custom-button-renderer

Comment: I can't even get this to compile. When I monkey with the using statements a bit, I still can't find a SetAllCaps method.

Comment: Please check the name space for the control. Make sure you are using android widget. The custom renderer should be part of the android project.

Comment: After banging around, I changed it to Control.SetAllCaps(false). Which compiles, but my text is still rendered in all upper case. ;(

Comment: Please update the code along with the code you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I made a test and found the issue is related to the version of `Xamarin.Forms`.

- If you are using Xamarin.Forms 4.6 , the solution you mentioned before does the trick , we just need to add `<item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>` into `style.xml` .
- If you're using the latest version(4.8) , the solution above does not work , we need to create custom renderer for the Button , pls copy the code into your android project.

  ```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Button), typeof(MyRenderer))]
    namespace YourNameSpace.Droid
    {
        class MyRenderer : ButtonRenderer
        {
            public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                if (e.OldElement != null)
                {
                    // Cleanup
                }

                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {
                    Control.SetAllCaps(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextTransform Property to None in your xaml controle

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).